# Why haven't my edits been bumping questions?

Tags: support, edits, bump

An edit to a question or answer always bumps the question, right?  Well, not in this case:

[image]

As you can see, I'm on the main page (which sorts by active (which is affected by edit bumping), right?).  Also, you can see that I made a change to that question 43 seconds before that screen shot and it's clearly lower than "How to insert code in code block" that was changed 5 hours ago.  (Come to think of it, why doesn't that question say who bumped it?

This was about 2 weeks ago, and I just saw it happen again today on Gaming.  I make an edit, click the logo, and am surprised when the question I just edited isn't bumped to the top.

What's going on here?

Comment: Does it only happen to questions you've edited, rather than ones edited by other people?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm I don't recall having noticed it affect edits by other people.  I've only seen this ever happen twice.

Comment: Might be something as simple as caching.

Comment: @AnnaLear I figured as much, but I'd like to hear it decisively.

Comment: From my experience, the front page seems to cache things for longer than for example a tag page, so it often takes a minute or two before it gets bumped.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The order of the homepage is heavily cached - it's one of the most hit pages on the site.

Simply wait a few minutes and it will adjust so that it is sorted correctly.