# Meta front page rarely slightly out of order

Tags: support, homepage

Something's not right about this.

[image]

I've seen this three times today: a question that should be at the top of the page (due to being changed most recently) is still stuck in its previous position. I can't reproduce it on demand, and it seems like it goes away on the next update. Anyone know something about this?

Comment: My assumption's always been that the per-question data is live, but the ordering is cached for a few minute period since it's more expensive. But I don't have an authoritative source for that.

Comment: I don't remember seeing it before though, whereas today I've now seen it four times.

Comment: It's done this for a while, although there was a time when it only updated after the order changed.

Comment: See also [Why haven't my edits been bumping questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114294/why-havent-my-edits-been-bumping-questions)

Comment: You make a good point - I'll tidy this up. I don't promise anything *between* pages, but individual result pages should be internally consistent.

Answer (score 6):

This is simply a cache issue. We set up the sort order of questions on the home page on a different interval than when we actually update the statistics on those questions. As a result, you may end up at times to see something that was very recently modified being still listed underneath something else. Once the sort order is refreshed, then the cycle begins anew.