# How are new questions arriving already answered?

Tags: discussion, homepage

Why is it that newly posted questions on https://stackoverflow.com/, less than a minute old, often appear on the homepage with dozens of views and several answers?

Even if I reload every second, the freshest questions are minimum 30 seconds old. But many are already answered, questions that take much more than 30 seconds to read and reply to in such detail. Is there a way see posts without this delay?

Are people using scripts/apps like [Live Home Page](https://stackapps.com/questions/2684/live-home-page-never-touch-the-refresh-button-on-the-home-page-of-a-stack-exch) or [open-so-frontend](http://code.google.com/p/open-so-frontend/) to see posts instantaneously? Or is there a badge that gives you access to posts the second they're posted, without the 30 second delay? Or ... time travel??

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you have examples of these magical questions? There is a facility for someone to type out their entire question *and* answer all at once and post them simultaneously, as well.

Comment: Some users are extremely fast.

Comment: FGITW, anybody?

Comment: Hah :) FGITW is right. Also, it didn't occur to me (duh) that the INTERESTING tab on the home page shows "time since last action", not "time since asked". Durrr...

Comment: I find it very ironic that after an hour there are numerous comments here, but no answers :)

Comment: It's all about the rep.

Comment: You should blame Jon Skeet ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The tag pages have the live update, which [the home page does not](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125677/new-feature-real-time-updates-to-questions-answers-and-inbox):

> Stack Overflow has a massive amount of activity so we have decided to limit this feature to tags only. Both the "newest" and "active" tab will have updates after first selecting a tag or tag combination.

Also, the homepage list [is cached on the server](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116263/meta-front-page-rarely-slightly-out-of-order).

So, others apparently are looking at specific tags they can answer, *and* get notified earlier.