# Keep old last activity when going to home page right after answering, or apply sort again

Tags: feature-request, sorting, top-questions

The home page questions are cached, but apparently after posting new answer the last activity is updated even in the cache causing weird behavior:

[image: wrong sort screenshot]

Looks like the question kept its old place, but displaying the real last activity time.

Related bug reports:

- [Meta front page rarely slightly out of order](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116263/meta-front-page-rarely-slightly-out-of-order)
- [Why haven't my edits been bumping questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114294/why-havent-my-edits-been-bumping-questions)

I offer a way to make it look better: either show the old last activity time, or apply the sort again so that it will be on top.

As questions also won't appear in the home page for about a minute after asking them, the first option might be more consistent with existing behavior.

Comment: @Arjan sure.. was hard to come with proper title, let me know if you have better suggestion. :)

Comment: This still happens and it's edits too.